# psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "usr"

Tags: postgresql

I have installed **PostgreSQL** on my server and when I try to connect to database I get this error (my password is correct but I get error):

```
[fuiba@web325 webapps]$ psql -h localhost -p 26880 -d univ_db -U usr
Password for user usr: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "usr"
```

My `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you have in your question. It must be something that is not in your question. Check the log files. Are you connecting to the right db cluster?

Comment: Can you log in it using `postgres` user ?

Comment: In the postgres log file _postgresql-Mon.log_ I have only the error: `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "usr"` repeated.

Comment: @Houari yes I can log in when I use the `postgres` user.

Comment: Perhaps you already did it: Can you reset the `usr` password just in case ?

Comment: I deleted the database and role and recreated them and it works. Thanks!